# Importing OSC library using TypeScript AMD fails to build osc object correctly

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, osc

I am trying to consume the browser portion of the OSC library here: https://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js in my TypeScript AMD website (Using RequireJS.)

I intend to write the definition file at least to the extent that I use it. However, when I import the (minified or not) osc-browser js file via require:

```
        //From the require config
        oscbrowser: ["/scripts/lib/osc.js/dist/osc-browser.min"],
...
        oscbrowser: {
            export: "osc"
        },
...
//From the typescript file
declare var osc;
```

Requirejs gives me the following javascript error at runtime:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "events" has not been loaded yet for
>   context: _. Use require([])

I have updated to the latest library per Colin's comment below and the error changes to reference the slip library.

> Uncaught Error: Module name "slip" has not been loaded yet for
>   context: _. Use require([])

When I pull in all components via the require config like so:

```
    EventEmitter: ["/scripts/lib/eventEmitter/EventEmitter"],
    slip: ["/scripts/lib/slip.js/dist/slip.min"],
    osc: ["/scripts/lib/osc.js/src/osc"],
    osctransports: ["/scripts/lib/osc.js/src/osc-transports"],
    oscbrowser: ["/scripts/lib/osc.js/src/platforms/osc-browser"],
```

and
        EventEmitter: {
            export: "EventEmitter"
        },
        osctransports: {
            deps: ["slip", "EventEmitter"]
        },
        oscbrowser: {
            export: "osc",
            deps: ["slip","EventEmitter", "osc", "osctransports"]
        },

The error returns to the events error:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "events" has not been loaded yet for
>   context: _. Use require([])

If I change the line in osc-transports.js from

```
EventEmitter = EventEmitter || require("events").EventEmitter;
```

to

```
EventEmitter = EventEmitter || require("EventEmitter") || require("events").EventEmitter;
```

because I believe that the prior require only works with the NPM version of EventEmitter the javascript error goes away and the library appears to work.

Does anyone with more experience with RequireJS than me have an idea as to why I can't use just the dist/ocs-browser versions of the library?

Comment: @colin-clark updated the library and now the only remaining issue is a problem with typescript's module import code as it relates to this bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2192 . As a work-around, osc can be assigned via a require statement inside the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the creator of osc.js. Until recently, osc.js didn't directly support asynchronous module loaders. After seeing your question, I added support to the library for the [universal module definition](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) style boilerplate, so osc.js [version 1.1.3](http://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js) and above should work with Require.js now.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update. Looks closer, though I am still getting an error in my use of the dist/osc-browser.js.  
`Module name "slip" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`  

Somehow, slip doesn't seem to be available at line 1659 and require can't find it.  

I'm continuing to dig into this, but I thought I'd drop a comment now.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting. I'm not doing that correctly either, I fear.

Comment: You'll also need to upgrade to [slip.js 1.0.2](https://github.com/colinbdclark/slip.js), which was updated to support AMD module loaders.

Comment: I have updated to the latest slip version as well, thanks. The only thing that seems unusual now is that I had to modify the line that pulls in EventEmitter.

Comment: You should not have to modify the source of osc.js at all to use it with Require.js. It looks to me like your require configuration is incorrect; the only osc.js file it should import is osc-module.min, not the individual osc, osc-transports, and osc-browser files. Instead, your require configuration should look [like this example in the osc.js unit test suite](https://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js/blob/master/tests/osc-module-tests.js#L11-L16).

Comment: Trying to test this, but bower will not seem to recognize the 'long' dependency. Still working on it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The example link I posted is for master, which contains the code for the upcoming 1.2 release of osc.js (which will support int64 arguments). Long is not needed for previous versions of osc.js. If you're using version osc.js 1.1.4 or earlier, please refer to [the documentation for the 1.1.4 version](https://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js/tree/1.1.4#using-oscjs-with-requirejs).

Comment: I've now got this working. It took some time to figure out that the last issue I was having was related to Typescript's handling of external modules. The standard import statement doesn't work, but I can embed a line like this._osc = require("osc"); in my handler and get the access I need. Thank you so much for the work on osc and here.